# Lost method since upgrading to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I cant find a method since I upgraded the Azure storage dlls.

The static method I cant find is: CloudTableClient.CreateTablesFromModel

**The old class:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudtableclient_methods.aspx

**This is the new class:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtableclient_methods.aspx

I did some searching but couldn't find a word about this being replaced or deleted.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storage client library 2.0 is quite different from the previous version and a number of methods have been removed in the newer version. This method is one of them. If you look under the remarks section on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudtableclient.createtablesfrommodel.aspx, it is recommended that you not use this method.

Since these 2 versions are quite different, it is recommended that you read up the following blog posts from the storage team before upgrading your code to use the latest version:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx

I also wrote a blog post about migrating code from storage client library 1.7 to 2.0 which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/